# Armature bone rotated 180

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, vertex-groups, pose-mode

In edit mode, I assign my figure's right thigh piece (selected in first picture) to it's respective vertex group that goes by the same name as the thigh bone. Once I assign, the thigh rotates 180 degrees on the Z axis for some reason. When I undo the assign (remove), it orients back to how it should look like as shown in the first picture. How can I assign the vertices with the vertex group without the thigh mesh rotating as shown by the second picture?
[image]

[image]

It must be something with the orientation of the bone itself. When I change the pole angle value of the yellow shin bone to 180 degrees, the thigh piece is correctly oriented but then it bends the wrong way when I move the body bone downward as shown by the third picture below.
[image]

There must be a simple fix, but I cannot find it nor can I easily edit the armature due to its various movement restrictions that I couldn't seem to remove either. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the bone roll for the bone?  It sounds like it's rotated 180 degrees on its y axis.

Comment: Thanks for showing me this new setting I haven't seen, but it appears that changing the "roll" value in the "transform" panel on the right (in edit mode) has the same effect as changing the pole angle value of the yellow shin bone in pose mode. I was messing around with all the values, trying to see if maybe a combination of them results in the desired outcome but the final state is always either the mesh looks fine but bends backwards, or bends forward but thigh is 180 flipped.

Comment: maybe bend the knees a bit in Edit mode? If it still doesn't work, please share your file (at least the armature + thigh): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I put the blender file on the link https://pasteall.org/blend/6e9be911590b4ff6b7c9d481cf0810ee. For potential copyright issues (as this isn't my mesh) I only included the thigh and hip piece for reference. Try moving "Bone.002" downward in pose mode and you'll see it bends backward. If you change the roll setting of the thigh bone in edit mode to -90 degrees, it'll bend forward but the mesh itself will flip 180 degrees on the z axis. Thanks for your help,

Comment: @moonboots I shared the file, let me know what's up with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bend the knees a bit forward in *Edit* mode:

[image]

And for the left leg, choose a *IK Pole Angle* of -90°:

[image]